# How can I make this kind of underline in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Today I found this underline on the internet and I am wondering if anyone of you can tell me how to recreate it in Adobe illustrator

[image]

Comment: Which part? The rugged black rectangle? The tapered white line? Both?

Comment: This  question is not clear, despite the image you posted.  Please at least say which part of the image you are trying to create, or are having difficulties with, also it would help to say what you tried already.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to create that effect.

A wide, short rectangle, say like 300 px wide and 8 px toll, filled with a gradient.

Make your gradient linear, 90 degrees vertical with 3 colors: white, grey in the middle then white on the other side. Give them equal width on the gradient slider.

Make both end white colors 0 transparency.

It should be getting close in look.

Adjust the darkness of the middle grey. Adjust the gradient slider. Make the whole rectangle transparency mode Multiple, 80% transparency, play with these settings until it looks like the example.

Also this gradient applied to a single stroke with no fill, like 3 inches wide, with the tapering at both ends stroke setting might help achieve the look.